# Understanding the equation for trending channels

Tags: statistics, logic, algorithms, data-analysis

I need to find an equation that decides the logic behind a list of ***Top Trending*** Channels. For example, for each channel i have the following data available,

1. Number of Active People in a channel
2. Number of messages in that channel

Take a look at the example below. There are three rows. The row 3 is supposed to be the Highest trending, followed by row 1 and then row 2. Now how can I convert this logic into an equation?

`Active People   |   Messages   |   Channel Ranking`

```
 5                    500          Second highest Channel (2)
 2                    1000         Third highest Channel (3)
 6                    5000         Highest Trending Channel (1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are infinitely many ways to do what you want. For example, you can rank the channels by giving each one a score, and then rank them from highest to lowest score. There are infinitely many ways to so that, to:

- $s=\#\text{active people}$
- $s=\#\text{active people} \cdot \#\text{messages}$
- $s=1000\cdot \#\text{active people} + \#\text{messages}$
- $s=\#\text{active people} + \sin(\#\text{messages})$

and so on and so on.

Now sure, some of the functions look stupid (why would you use a $\sin$ function?), but they give the ranking you want, and with no further detail, that's all you can say.

Comment: The first proposed metric does not reproduce the desired ranking, but the second proposed metric does.   You are right (of course) that there are any number of ways to match the one example.